# Now Ubuntu isn't booting. I get a black screen with flashing curor

Tags: boot

I don't know what happened.  I was trying to back up my system - ironically - and now the SSD won't boot.

It isn't corrupt, it just won't boot.

I can boot from a USB stick and can mount the drive.  The directories are there, so it isn't the data is gone.

I now don't have a working machine.   I am using it booting via the USB.  So no history, no book marks, etc.   So it is difficult to go back and show exactly what happened/I did.

What I see is/was indicative of a grub fault.  (From results on searches and the replies implying that this would work.)
I have read and tried fixing the GRUB.   Alas that doesn't seem to be the problem.

On boot, I see the spinning circle for 20.10.
The screen blanks, then the spinning circle returns.
Then the screen goes black and I have/see a cursor top left of the screen.

Pressing Ctl Alt F3 I can get up a terminal.
But then I am stuck.

(Something else I've tried)

I know there is an option to "repair" a messed up install.
I start the install and there is an option to repair the install mentioned.

Alas when I get to that page, it is ghosted out.
Yet, the third option says it will install Ubuntu 20.10 beside Ubuntu 20.10.
I was reluctant to try this, but did start it.
But a couple of screens later it is telling me that partition resizing is about to happen.
The SSD is a 500GB.
I know it has a small partition and a main one.
So I am not understanding what it happening and so haven't done that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115957/discussion-on-question-by-recently-updated-ubuntu-user-now-ubuntu-isnt-booting).

Comment: After 4 weeks of research, I have now got the SSD back up and working.